# Parse through a struct and returning values to C# from C++ function

Tags: c++, struct, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-component

.h file

```
public ref class Lockscreen sealed
{
public:
    Lockscreen();
    _BADGE_INFORMATION GetLockscreenNotificationData();
};
```

.cpp file

```
_BADGE_INFORMATION Lockscreen::GetLockscreenNotificationData()
{

GetNotificationsSnapshot(&snapshot);
_BADGE_INFORMATION badgeInfo;
return badgeInfo;}
```

The above two are my header and cpp files. I have to return the struct _BADGE_INFORMATION back to my C# code from the cpp file. But while doing so am getting an error that says, "signature of public member contains native type _BADGE_INFORMATION", this data is very crucial to my app, and I have never ever worked on C++ before.I need to serialize this data and send it back to my C# code. Can someone tell me how. Or suggested any other means to get the data of the struct. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What really is _BADGE_INFORMATION? There are different ways to send data from unmanaged code to managed. You may serialize for example you data to xml or json in C++ code and deserialize in C# code. If you want pass you data as return type see this question: [Passing struct from unmanaged C++ to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519729/passing-struct-from-unmanaged-c-to-c-sharp), may be it will be usefull.